# change format of uniq -c command

Tags: awk, sed, sort, text-formatting, uniq

I want to get the unique words and its count from a file. 
When I run the bellow command,

```
sort words.txt | uniq -c



   2 america
   4 and
   1 england
   1 file
   1 for
   1 place
```

But I want the output in following format

```
america,2
and,4
england,1
file,1
for,1
place,1
```

My input file is around 30-40Gb. So what is the best way to print the output in this format?

Comment: pipe it into `sed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `awk` line to the end of your command. For example,

```
sort words.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2","$1}'
```

Basically, it takes the second column and places it before the first column while separating it by a comma. I do not know how expensive it is to run it on a 30-40Gb file.

Answer (score 1):

we can do with awk itself...

Try below,

```
awk '{j[$0]++} END {for (i in j) print i","j[i]}' words.txt
```

Comment: @drewbenn: you mean few _duplicates_ (thus _many_ distinct values, filling memory). And with GNU awk 4 up setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` will give the sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sort words.txt | uniq -c | sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]) (.+)/\2,\1/g'
```

Tested with GNU, Busybox and BSD implementations of `sed`. Output
would be:

```
america,2
and,4
england,1
file,1
for,1
place,1
```

I ran a test on 200MB file and noticed that `sed` itself is still
quite fast:

```
$ time sed  -E 's/^ *([0-9]) (.+)/\2,\1/g'  HUGE | head
america,2
and,4
england,1
file,1
for,1
place,1
america,2
and,4
england,1
file,1

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.006s
```

But saving data to the file on disk takes a lot of time with both `-i`
option and by redirecting output using `>` shell operator:

```
$ time sed -i -E 's/^ *([0-9]) (.+)/\2,\1/g'  HUGE
real    0m45.793s
user    0m31.965s
sys     0m13.574s
$ time sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]) (.+)/\2,\1/g'  HUGE > HUGE_NO_I
real    0m29.016s
user    0m28.684s
sys     0m0.119s
```